# Rails 3 UJS run a while loop when waiting for an ajax:callback

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ujs

This is my javascript for a `:remote => true` form.

Currently, when the form is submitted, this function runs once. (the width increases by 5%.

However, I want this animation to run in a loop so that the width keeps increasing by increments of 5% until I get an ajax:success or an ajax:failure callback, at which point I want to jump into another function.

```
$('#new_message').bind('ajax:loading', function() {
  $('#send_bar').animate({
    width: '+=5%'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a function that runs the animation, and then in the [completion parameter](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), pass the the function so that it calls itself recursively:

```
var start_animation = function() {
  $('#send_bar').animate({width: '+=5%'}, 5000, 'linear', start_animation);
}
```

In the loading function, call the function to begin the animation:

```
$('#new_message').bind('ajax:loading', function() {
  start_animation();
});
```

Then in your bind to ajax:success and ajax:failure, call [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$('#new_message').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $('#send_bar').stop();
});

$('#new_message').bind('ajax:failure', function() {
  $('#send_bar').stop();
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. I almost got it.. Doesn't seem to quite be working for me.  I can't get the animation to start (see update)

Comment: Good to hear.  Was it something wrong in my answer that you were having a problem with? Thought I'd ask just in case I need to update it for others.

Comment: Nope, my own mistake.  the only thing with your answer is maybe this is better?: